# how to use Linked list in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, linked-list

I have an array of objects and I have a constraint that if I need to remove an object from the middle of the array I need to run check against the element in the previous and the next object after deletion to make sure it's not matching.

SO ,I figured I will use linked list to implement the logic inside the class , so how i can use linked list in Angular Js or if there another way to do that ?

Comment: sounds good..but have to implement yourself or find a library that does it for you. Very simple to get current index and add or subtract to get siblings though

Comment: I ended with this solution and looks like it works perfect , I will post my answer and please check if you think there is something better to do.

Comment: Abebars, did you ever post your answer?